# images not visible in form

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

i want to show images not visible in form ..

code

```
  <div><img id="imgsuces" src="images/sucess.jpg" visible="false" alt="success" />
 <asp:Label runat="server" id="StatusLabel" />
</div>
<div><img id="imgfalied" src="images/falied.jpg" visible="false" alt="success" />
 <asp:Label runat="server" id="Label2" />
</div>
```

i add this in upload form then when i run this form then this images are visible ...but i want when user upload document and when it success the image will be shown of sucess and when document failed then image will be show falied .

how i get it?

Comment: Can I have more code for codebehind?

Comment: When you do you set `Visible` to `true`?  You also don't have `runat="server"` on them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do some manipulation in server side(`visible="false"`) add `runat=server`

```
<img id="imgfalied" src="images/falied.jpg" visible="false" 
     runat='server' alt="success" />
```

Or make it in client side using `style="display:none"`

```
<img id="imgfalied" src="images/falied.jpg"  
     style="display:none" alt="success" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Add **runat=server** in the img tags and set the visibility from the code behind.